# Why is my KNN model overfitting?

Tags: overfitting, k-nearest-neighbour

I have 20K voters geocoded and labelled with 4 classes of voting intention. I want to predict based on neighbors intention which looks correlated on a map. Using K nearest neighbors with lat/lon scores 65% on a random validation set; and similar score with leaveoneout. The validation score for each ward ranges from 55% to 75%.

However if I treat each ward separately as a validation set and train on the rest then my scores are 30-40% for most wards. Even the best achieves only 58%. What can explain this?

This is code for random validation sample:

```
xlab = lab[["lat", "lon"]]
ylab = lab.target
xtrain, xvalid, ytrain, yvalid = train_test_split(xlab, ylab, test_size=.1)
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(weights="distance", n_neighbors=20, n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
clf.score(xvalid, yvalid)
```

This is for taking a ward as validation sample:

```
for validw in lab.wardname.unique():
    train, valid = lab[lab.wardname!=validw], lab[lab.wardname==validw]
    xtrain, ytrain = train[["lat", "lon"]], train.target
    xvalid, yvalid = valid[["lat", "lon"]], valid.target
    xtrain, ytrain = shuffle(xtrain, ytrain)
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(weights="distance", n_neighbors=20, n_jobs=-1)
    clf.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
    print(validw, clf.score(xvalid, yvalid))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I know the answer. The validation phase looks for nearest neighbours in the training sample. So the validation sample has to be from the same space. One cannot train on London and then apply the model to Birmingham.

For this dataset there are some correct matches near the border with the training space but mostly it will be guesswork.